# How to disable clipboard sharing in Hyper-V Enhanced Session Mode?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, clipboard

OS: Windows 10 enterprise

I have to use some softwares for working.

These softwares could sell my privacy.

So, I installed them on Hyper_V,
and enabled Enhanced Session Mode for using camera and video-talking (for work).

But I have no idea how to disable clipboard sharing between host and guest.

VMware is too expensive and consume too much resource (CPU Fan is noisy), VirtualBox is not reliable(too many bugs).

Need help

Answer (score 1):

To disable clipboard sharing but still KEEP the Enhanced Session Mode:

1. Disconnect the current session
2. In the Hyper-V Manager, right-click on your virtual machine, select "Edit Session Settings" [image]
3. Select "Show Options" [image]
4. Select "Local Resources" tab
5. Now you can uncheck the "Clipboard" option [image]

Answer (score -1):

In the Hyper-V Manager, select the **Host** machine in the left tree, click on Hyper-V Settings in the Actions pane to the right, and deselect the checkboks in the `Enhance Session Mode Policy` in the Server section and `Enhance Session Mode` in the User section.

Reference [here](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/57136-turn-off-hyper-v-enhanced-session-mode-windows-10-a.html).